# How can i make the images smaller without losing quality?

Tags: html, css

```
.review {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        border-radius: 55;
}
```

This is how I have my code right now. I need help making all 3 images smaller without losing quality.  Every time I add width and height to .review img, it squishes my images, and the last image disappears.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1):

To make images smaller without losing quality, you can use the CSS `max-width` property to limit the maximum width of the images while maintaining their aspect ratio. This way, the images will be responsive, and the quality won't be compromised.

Here's an example of how you can modify your CSS code:

```css
.review {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border-radius: 55;
}

.review img {
    max-width: 100%; /* Set the maximum width to 100% of the container */
    height: auto;    /* Allow the height to adjust proportionally */
}
```

In this example, I've added a selector for `.review img` to target all images inside the `.review` container. The `max-width: 100%` ensures that the images won't exceed the width of their container, and `height: auto` maintains the aspect ratio.

Now, when you add this to your existing code, it should help make the images smaller without losing quality:

```css
.review {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    border-radius: 55;
}

.review img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Adjusting the `max-width` property allows you to control how much smaller you want the images to be while ensuring they remain responsive and maintain their quality.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the width or height while maintaining the aspect ratio and set a unit for the `border-radius` property.

```
.review {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.review img {
    width: 100px;
    height: auto; 
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```